# Breaking a subsection title

Tags: line-breaking, subsection

I am trying to break a subsection title using `\\`

It was working before, but now for some reason, it is not working at all! I have done lots of edits and formatting adjustments to the whole document. I do not know what is exactly causing this problem.

In my old document, I used

```
\subsection{Heterogeneous Effects for Retail Salespeople \\ 
            Working for Merging Parties}
```

It popped up this error "Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): removing `\' on input line 344", but it was working.

I am now using the same command now, but it is not working anymore.

Do you have other suggestions for breaking a subsection title?

I tried \newline, but it is not working.

Comment: This is a warning, not an error. Use `\texorpdfstring{\\}{}`

Comment: The problem here is that `\\ ` isn't allowed in a bookmark.  Bury it: `... Salespeople \texorpdfstring{\\}{}Working ...`. Be careful to avoid a double space that would happen if you have a space both before and after the `\texorpdfstring` insertion.